# moving a loopcut along a straight line

Tags: modeling

[image: loopcut]

I would like to slide the loopcut I added so that it remains always parallel to face a.
It completely overlaps the face b at the end instead, when sliding from a to b.

Answer (score 5):

You could also slide newly created ring to the face, then start a new slide operation with Shift + V, constrain it with C if needed and hit E for Even Offset:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Done.
Set: Pivot point individual origin
Transform: Normal
then G and pressed 2 times the axis key (z).

Comment: I would have done it as @MartynasŽiemys, could you please illustrate what you have done? If other users come here in the future it would be helpful... as I see it, if I take your answer as it is, you start with a loop cut somewhere inbetween - which is not parallel to face A. So maybe there is a step missing to get it parallel. Then you set the _Transform Orientation_ to _Normal_, but if you then move with G and press Z twice, you don't move on normal Z axis, but global Z... and it is not necessary to set the _Pivot Point_ to _Individual Origins_, but _Median Point_ works as well.

Comment: Have to agree with @GordonBrinkmann.. that seems to be exactly what the E constraint  to GG  is for :) I can't see a difference, except more work. Could be wrong, as always ..

Comment: @RobinBetts Not only more work, if you just do it exactly as explained, you won't get the correct result. And you don't have the advantage of clamping so it stops automatically when you reach the end point.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yup . And the Z is normal to the face, not the individual edges...